# How can make an UWP Control clickable even if it is transparent?

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I want to make a Grid clickable even if it is 100% transparent. The `Tapped` is not fired unless I set a non-transparent `Background`. Is there any way to acheive this on the Grid itself or any other Control?

Comment: What's your XAML code? Usually it is clickable if `Background="Transparent"` but I have no idea what you mean by "even if it is transparent".

Comment: Ah, I realise there is a difference beteween `Background="Transparent"` and not having a Background property set at all. Setting the property made it clickable. Write it as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a difference between not using the `Background` attribute and using `Background="Transparent"`. The element cannot be clicked when no `Background` is set, whereas setting it to `Transparent` makes the element clickable (until you disable this by setting `IsHitTestVisible="False"`).